# how to convert a float into binary using struct.unpack?

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to convert a float into binary.

I'm using the module struct. For instance, with the value of 3.5, when I execute this line :

```
struct.pack('>f',3.5)
```

I get this :

```
b'@`\x00\x00'
```

I suppose the two x00 x00 represent hexadecimal values for each bytes used but what about the b and '@` ?

Comment: "*I'm trying to convert a float into binary.*" - Can you give an example of what you mean by "binary"? What sort of output are you seeking?

Comment: The bytes object you received contains the bytes you need. You're just getting confused by how it's displayed. You don't need to fix anything.

Comment: @Robᵩ basically i want to convert a float like 3.5 into a binary value like : 01000000011000000000000000000000 ( in form of string )

Answer (score 1):

The format string `'>f'` means

`'f'`  IEEE 754 binary32  (4 bytes, like a C float)

`'>'`  [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order, standard size

That's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).  The characters `@` and `` ` `` are just part of your numeric data (3.5) when represented as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  It's probably more helpful to look at these 4 bytes represented as binary:

```
>>> format(ord('@'), '08b')
'01000000'
>>> format(ord('`'), '08b')
'01100000'
>>> format(ord('\x00'), '08b')
'00000000'
```

So concatenated as a 32-bit float, that's has a binary representation like this:

```
>>> ''.join(format(x, '08b') for x in b'@`\x00\x00')
'01000000011000000000000000000000'
```

To convert the binary representation back to float by hand, read about [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) here, and split it up into components instead of bytes.  This is sign bit, exponent (8 bit unsigned int, [offset-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary)), and fraction (23 bits):

```
0 10000000 11000000000000000000000
```

The exponent here is just 1, because that representation offset by 127:

```
>>> int('10000000', 2) - 127
1
```

The fractional part is like 1.11<sub>2</sub>, i.e.

```
>>> (2**0 + 2**-1 + 2**-2)*2
3.5
```

With a positive sign bit (-1)<sup>**0**</sup> = 1, and an exponent 1, that's the number 3.5 (and it happens to be one of the numbers which can be represented exactly as a float).

Comment: thanks. exactly what i need. just cant use the format function because we havent learned what that function does in class yet.

Comment: You can get similar information from the built-in function [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin).

Comment: yes. but i cant use that function in class either. again i'll remember it, i will probably need it later

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem - the `b''` literal is already binary bytes type (an old tradition, since 2.x).

```
>>> struct.pack('>f',3.5)
b'@`\x00\x00'
>>> a = struct.pack('>f',3.5)
>>> type(a)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: how do i interpret what i see ?

Comment: @oozma This. Is. An. Immutable. Iterable. Of. Ints.